# Stringify parameters in macro

Tags: c++11

```cpp
#define MY_ASSERT_TEST(parA, parB, parC) do {                                           \
    for (int i = 0; i < TestStruct::parB::TestData_parC_TestOptions_Len; i += 1)        \
    {                                                                                   \
        if (parA == TestStruct::parB::TestData_parC_TestOptions_i)                      \
            return;                                                                     \
    }                                                                                   \
    MY_LOG("MY_ASSERT_TEST Warning: %s", #parA);                                        \
} while(0)
```

It replaces `parB` correctly, but not `parC` and `i`.

I have tried something like `TestStruct::parB::TestData_#parC_TestOptions_#i`.

or `TestStruct::parB::TestData_(#parC)_TestOptions_(#i)`

Comment: `i` is not a macro parameter and cannot be stringified as such.  If you want to maintain a dynamic number of variables, I recommend [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: It isn't clear what you want your macro to expand to. Can you sow a call, the intended replacement, and the actual replacement?